# The name System.IO.File.Move does not exist in current context(VS 2019)

Tags: c#, system.io.file

```
using System.IO;

string srcFile = @"C:\Users\Anne\results.trx";
string destFile = @"C:\Users\Anne\results.trx2";
System.IO.File.Move(srcFile, destFile);
```

Why is the `System.IO.File` reference not recognized?

Comment: Try "Clean Project", close VS, open again and build project. What happens?

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have the same error.

Comment: The snippet above - is this actually how the file looks like? (I guess not)
Have you tried if the same thing happens in a newly created Console-App's Main()?

Answer (score 0):

Your code execute just fine, the issue lies elsewhere and you'll need to provide more details of your project's setup.

Remember to try restarting etc. as well.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue was caused by incorrect placing System.IO.Move() - I placed in within a class but outside method brackets.